# MySQLi Select Serialized Data

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to select serialized data from a table using the following query.

The table looks like this: [image]

```
$dbConn = db_connect();
$dbConn->set_charset("utf8");
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare("
SELECT data
FROM wp_vfb_pro_entries
WHERE entries_id = 1
");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($raw_data);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

var_dump($raw_data);
```

`var_dump` always returns `string(0) ""` when I try to select from the `data` column. If I try to select anything else it works, but for some reason, selecting the `data` column returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure? how exactly you print for example form_id?

Comment: @Akam I just changed to `SELECT form_id` and then `echo $raw_data;` and it returns 2

Comment: check everything again, over wise this is impossible :(

Comment: Why are you using `prepare` on a query without any `?` (parameterized variables) in it?

Comment: @RocketHazmat What should I be using instead?

Comment: You can just do `$result = $dbConn->query('SELECT ...');` and then `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();  $raw_data = $row['data'];`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you! That actually solved my initial issue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `->prepare()` here.  That's only when you want to use parameterized queries.

Since your ID is hard-coded in your query, you can just do `->query()`.

```
$result = $dbConn->query('
  SELECT data
  FROM wp_vfb_pro_entries
  WHERE entries_id = 1
');

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$raw_data = $row['data'];
```

Comment: Do you know any good resources to learn more about parameterized queries? Had similar problems understanding prepare(). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @StenW: The best I can do is show you the docs for prepare: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and PHP's guide to parameterized queries: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thank you and a quick follow up. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php states that "A prepared statement or a parameterized statement is used to execute the same statement repeatedly..." does this mean that a prepare statement and a parameterized statement is the same thing?

Comment: @StenW: Yes.  Different terms for the same thing.  A prepared statement and a parameterized query can mean the same thing.

Comment: Awsome, I am really starting to love this site. Straight answers, from great people :)

Comment: @StenW: Yep.  That's how things work around here!  It's a great community :-)